# 35 minutes between connections on Newark airport

Tags: short-connections, united-airlines, ewr

I am flying from Chicago to Aruba with a connecting flight in Newark. Between the landing time and take off time is 35 minutes. Is it a viable travel plan?  I am flying United.

Comment: An important 'detail' - are both flights a part of booked flight on single booking site/airline?

Comment: if you have to collect luggage and check it in again then i dont think so

Comment: yes the flight was booked on single booking site/airline. O'hare had no direct flights that day.

Comment: Single booking should help, but you could have a long run in Terminal C (most of United's traffic)  If you're in the back of the plane, you may waste a lot of that just getting off.

Comment: @Newton why’ll he have to do that? Chicago to Newark is domestic.

Comment: @nikhil Because when Newton asked, OP had not indicated whether this was a single booking or not. *[Changing planes at Newark Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38473)* and *[Is 45 mins enough in Newark airport terminal C to change the plane for connecting flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42106)* may be informative.

Answer (score 3):

If your inbound flight is on schedule... and you run... you'll probably be fine.  You may not even have to run, if your gates are close together.

If anything goes wrong, it is extremely likely you will miss your connecting flight.

Answer (score 0):

Things you should calculate yourself, Considering the changes in a scenario which may occur surprisingly.

1. It should be single booking, (Code-sharing by Air-Line is fine)
2. The gates should be close enough, and you need to take an intra-airport transport.
3. Your first flight should not be delayed. In such cases, the airlines give you the other options for single bookings. But if you have not done the single booking, it will cost you to book another flight.
4. In case you reach a bit late, they may ask you to run. So be ready for that.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
-AG